# No export options for Modeling Project on Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

We have created a new Modeling Project on Visual Studio 2012 to have all of the class and sequence diagrams, however there is no option to export the diagrams to images like the diagrams created via "View class diagram" option in a Class Library.

Why? How can I export the diagrams from this project template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been trying to find a way to export the diagrams and now I realized that selecting the elements of the diagram, copying and pasting to another application (like MSPaint or Word) does work.

However, the header of the diagram (with the name of the class diagram) is ignored.